# Unable to write/mount disks with iscsi reservation and multipathd. Using Pacemaker and iscsi fence agent

Tags: iscsi, sas, pacemaker

I have two iscsi target servers in a pacemaker cluster connected to a Dell MD1200, I can get the scsi reservations recorded with the multipath.conf key configured in each server, but I can't write to the array reliably/ever on either system.
Only if I shutdown everything and boot only one node can I mount and write to the array. I feel like I'm missing a configuration that sets the primary system with the reservation key otherthan multipathd

Here are my configurations:

multipath.conf node1

```
defaults {
        user_friendly_names    no
        find_multipaths        yes
        reservation_key        3bcc0000
        path_selector          "service-time 0"
        path_grouping_policy   group_by_serial
        polling_interval       10
        uid_attribute          ID_SERIAL
        prio                   const
        path_checker           tur
        rr_min_io              100
        max_fds                8192
        rr_weight              priorities
        failback               immediate
        no_path_retry          fail
}

blacklist_exceptions {
        property "(SCSI_IDENT_|ID_WWN)"
}

blacklist {
}
```

multipath.conf node2

```
defaults {
        user_friendly_names    no
        find_multipaths        yes
        reservation_key        3bcc0001
        path_selector          "service-time 0"
        path_grouping_policy   group_by_serial
        polling_interval       10
        uid_attribute          ID_SERIAL
        prio                   const
        path_checker           tur
        rr_min_io              100
        max_fds                8192
        rr_weight              priorities
        failback               immediate
        no_path_retry          fail
}

blacklist_exceptions {
        property "(SCSI_IDENT_|ID_WWN)"
}

blacklist {
}
```

iscsi fence agent config:

```
pcs stonith config
 Resource: vol1-san01_fence (class=stonith type=fence_scsi)
  Attributes: devices=/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f6b607,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f71b8b,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f71c27,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f71c37,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f7df7b,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f80333,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f8070f,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f8072b,/dev/mapper/35000cca0131663d4,/dev/mapper/35000cca01317b5d8,/dev/mapper/35000cca01317bb94,/dev/mapper/35000cca01317beb8 key=3bcc0000 pcmk_host_list=sphqsan01 pcmk_monitor_action=metadata
  Meta Attrs: provides=unfencing
  Operations: monitor interval=60s (vol1-san01_fence-monitor-interval-60s)
 Resource: vol1-san02_fence (class=stonith type=fence_scsi)
  Attributes: devices=/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f6b607,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f71b8b,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f71c27,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f71c37,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f7df7b,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f80333,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f8070f,/dev/mapper/35000c500b6f8072b,/dev/mapper/35000cca0131663d4,/dev/mapper/35000cca01317b5d8,/dev/mapper/35000cca01317bb94,/dev/mapper/35000cca01317beb8 key=3bcc0001 pcmk_host_list=sphqsan02 pcmk_monitor_action=metadata
  Meta Attrs: provides=unfencing
  Operations: monitor interval=60s (vol1-san02_fence-monitor-interval-60s)
```

Checking reservations (node2 is currently disabled):

```
[root@sphqsan01 ~]# /usr/bin/sg_persist -n -i -k -d /dev/mapper/35000c500b6f6b607
  PR generation=0x79, 2 registered reservation keys follow:
    0x3bcc0000
    0x3bcc0000
```